# Implement an interface with a nested object

Tags: c#, interface

How can an interface be implemented by a nested object without mapping every member of the interface.  How can last two lines of the example below be replaced by a single code line which maps the whole interface to the object?

```
public interface IIndexer 
{
    int A { get; }
    void B(int value);
}

public interface IBuilder : IIndexer
{
    int Q { get; }
}

public class Indexer: IIndexer
{
    int A { get; set; }
    void B(int value) {.....}
}

public class Builder 
{
    // Implement members declared in IBuilder
    int Q { get; set; }  

    // Nested object implements IIndexer
    Indexer Index = new();  
    
    // Implement each member of IIndexed individually
    int IIndexer.A => Index.A;  
    void IIndexer.B(int value) => Index.B(value);
}
```

Comment: I am confused: `Builder` does not _attempt_ to implement any of those interfaces?

Comment: But alas: One way I tend to avoid, too would be to switch from composition to inheritance: `Builder` could `is-a Indexer` instead of `has-a`. Of course, that comes with caveats.

Comment: Why `Builder` does not inherit from `Indexer`? That seems to be what you want. Edit: so what @Fildor says in his 2nd comment

Comment: BTW: `Indexer` does not implement `IIndexer`, neither. Members would need to be `public`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter That would still be an error. It could implement `IIndexer` though which would fix the problem.

Comment: @DavidG: Why it would be an error? Of course `Indexer` needs to have public members

Comment: @TimSchmelter Because the code inside `Builder` explicitly says it is implementing the interface. If you inherit from `Indexer` then those lines can't have `IIndexer.A` for example

Comment: @DavidG I think that is just an artifact from OP's attempts to get to what they want. I for one implied that inheritance is done correctly, if so.

Comment: @DavidG: yes, but these lines are what OP wants to get rid of

Comment: Yeah, this question is a mess.

Comment: @OP: I am aware of the "Composittion over inheritance" 'rule' - but that is just a mild guideline, not a universal law of physics. When it's appropriate that one thing "is" another thing, then sometimes it's totally ok to design it that way.

Answer (score 4):

Simply reflect the inheritance between the two interfaces in the class hierarchy:

```cs
public class Indexer : IIndexer
{
    public int A { get; } = 0;

    public void B(int value)
    {
    }
}

public class Builder : Indexer, IBuilder
{
    public int Q { get; } = 42;
}
```

The `Builder` class inherits `A` and `B` from `Indexer` and does not need to implement them.

You can also make the `A` and `B` virtual in `Indexer`. This enables `Builder` to override the implementations of `Indexer`.

Comment: Thank-you Olivier.
This solution can be used in my situation, and will be.
As it not a solution for all situations regretfully no green tick.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. If `Builder` derives from `IBuilder` it must implement all methods in the interface, including all methods in `IIndexer`. If you want to forward the calls to `Index` you need to explicitly do this. There is nothing preventing you from having multiple `Index`-objects, so you need to be explicit.

There are some refactoring tools that can generate code to delegate implementations of an interface to a member. This is often quite useful when writing decorators. So my advice would be to just create the code, put it in a region if it is large enough, and forget about it.

You *could* make `Builder` *derive* from `Indexer`, and this would remove the need to implement `A` and `B()`, but I assume this is not the intent.